# Change type of state depending on props - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have a form component "AddBooking" that takes the following prop:

```
type AddBookingProps = { edit?: Booking };
```

If this "edit" prop is passed in, I want to render the form with the values set. If it isn't passed in, it becomes a "create" blank form. This is how I'm trying to use the state.

```
const [currentBooking, setBooking] = useState<NewBooking | Booking>(
  edit ? edit : emptyBooking
);
```

emptyBooking is just a load of empty strings in a NewBooking type to initialize the state.

The difference between the types "Booking" and "NewBooking" is that "Booking" has a required "_id" type whereas "NewBooking" doesn't.
The methods I have for editBooking and addBooking required types "Booking" and "NewBooking" respectively. This is where I get type errors:

```
if (edit) {
      bookingContext.editBooking(currentBooking);
      handleClose();
    } else {
      bookingContext.addBooking({
        ...currentBooking,
        bookedBy: uContext.user.username
      });
      handleClose();
    }
```

I get a type error when calling editBooking:

> Argument of type 'NewBooking | Booking' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Booking'.
> Property '_id' is missing in type 'NewBooking' but required in type 'Booking'.

Any ideas how I can get around this without the "any" type?
Thanks so much

Comment: In `NewBooking` add `_id` as required and in `emptyBooking` set `_id` equals to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe a use case for a type guard https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

A function you define to check that `_id` is actually on the type. This is probably good practice as you don't want the user to edit a booking that doesn't yet exist

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. For anyone else reading, the exact link above is deprecated so the new page I referenced here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing. I changed if(edit) to if("_id" in currentBooking)